# How can I store multiple server addresses for a web server in a client?

Tags: ip-address

I thought of storing the addresses in a resource file, as a string table, but iterating through them like that will be a drag.
I do not want to hard-code them. What else can I do?

Comment: The whole point of having files is to store stuff in it. You can hard-code an initial collection of addresses and [serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00hh13h0.aspx) them. If they're sensitive you should also encrypt them. Alternatively you can create a distributed network and [ask it to tell you the addresses](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_Client_Node_Discovery). Why would it be a drag? How many addresses do you have?

Comment: I have to be able to change these addresses when the servers are moved on other machines.

Comment: Then keep the old machines alive for the transition period and have them redirect the clients. Update the client to point to the new servers. There are security considerations with this, so if you are using the client for anything sensitive (ie. if you do any form of authentication) consider encrypting the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put all of them separated by semi colon ";" and load it at the application first load and split that to an array and iterate over them any time you want